# (Dis)connectedness of $GL(n, \mathbb R)$

Tags: general-topology

How do I prove that $GL(n,\mathbb R)$, with the relative topology from $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, is not connected?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  Recall that  **det**  $ : GL_n(R) \to \Bbb R^\times $ is a continuous surjective map and continuous image of a connected set is connected.Can you conclude now?

Comment: yes that helps a lot thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the map $\det:GL(n,\Bbb R)\to \Bbb R^\times$ which sends any invertible matrix $A$ to its (nonzero) determinant $\det A$. This is a continuous map since it is given by a polynomial in the entries of $A$. Then $\det^{-1}(0,\infty)$ and $\det^{-1}(-\infty,0)$ are disjoint nonempty open sets whose union is all of $GL(n,\Bbb R)$.